# How to include the magento product comparison in single column layouts?

Tags: magento, layout

So I've been trying to include the default product comparison box into a single column layout with out any success. 
I eventually just copied the full code found it
product/compare/sidebar.phtml

into my 1column.phtml file.

It looks fine, when i click on a product to add it to the comparison a message appears saying that it is successfully added, but the list only shows two products to compare even though i should have more, and it only compares just the two products that it shows.

How do i do this. I am very new at Magento and would appreciate any help.

FYI the Magento version I am using is 1.8.1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone who has the same issue, turns out I just needed to re-index the products. Ended up wasting two days on this :(

Answer (score 0):

i can be setting issue.

Goto `admin>System>Configuration>Catalog>Catalog`.

Then goto Tab `Recently Viewed/Compared Products` and here you have  find how product `will be shown` in `compare`